# Android: Firebase "topics" notification doesn't handle in my App

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

With specific fcm token (per user) it works perfectly. Now I want to add "topics" notification, so I've added subscription:

```
public class MyInstanceIDListenerService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {

    private static final String TAG = LogUtils.makeLogTag(MyInstanceIDListenerService.class);

    /**
     * Called if InstanceID token is updated. This may occur if the security of
     * the previous token had been compromised. Note that this is also called
     * when the InstanceID token is initially generated, so this is where
     * you retrieve the token.
     */
    @Override
    public void onTokenRefresh() {
            // Get updated InstanceID token.
            String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
            LogUtils.LOGD(TAG, "Refreshed FCM token: " + refreshedToken);
            ...
            subscribeTopics();                         
    }

    /**
     * Subscribe to any FCM topics of interest, as defined by the TOPICS constant.
     */
    private void subscribeTopics() {
        for (String topic : MyFcmListenerService.TOPICS) {
            FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic(topic);
        }
    }
}
```

And in my receiver this kind of notifications doesn't handle:

```
public class MyFcmListenerService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    private static final String TAG = LogUtils.makeLogTag(MyFcmListenerService.class);

    // Topics
    public static final String TOPIC = "/topics/";
    public static final String UPGRADE = "upgrade";
    public static final String[] TOPICS = {UPGRADE};

    // Downstream type messages
    public static final String PROFIL = "profil";
    ...


    protected WebServicesModule getWebServicesModule() {
        return MyApplication.getInstance().getDataHolder().getWebServicesModule();
    }

    public MyFcmListenerService() {
    }

    /**
     * Called when message is received.
     *
     * @param message
     */
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage message) {

       String from = message.getFrom();
       Map data = message.getData();

       LogUtils.LOGD(TAG, "[FCM] Topic message received from [" + from + "]");

       ...
```

The function onMessageReceived() is never called when I send this notification (from Postman):

[image]

with this header configuration:

[image]

Thank guys for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You are subscribing to the topics when `onTokenRefresh()` is invoked.  That method is invoked infrequently and [only for specific events](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/iid/FirebaseInstanceIdService.html#onTokenRefresh()).  Perform the topic subscription on some other event, for example, `onCreate()` of your app's MainActivity.